# Launching influxdb console on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jmeter, influxdb

I have downloaded the tar file for influxdb 1.2.0 and have also extracted it to a folder, in the config file I have enabled the admin and HTTP ports respectively to 8083 and 8086. I also ran the influx and influxd services in the usr/bin section but when I hit //localhost:8083 the admin panel is not displayed in the browser. How can I get this up and running in Ubuntu, all suggestions are invited...

Comment: can you show the logs ?

Comment: Which logs do you need?

Comment: influxdb logs on console and in file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start clean:

1. [Download InfluxDB version 1.2.0](https://community.influxdata.com/t/install-specific-version-of-influxdb-in-ubuntu-16-04/4631)

   ```
   wget https://dl.influxdata.com/influxdb/releases/influxdb_1.2.0_amd64.deb
   ```
2. [Install it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/how-to-install-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt)

   ```
   dpkg -i influxdb_1.2.0_amd64.deb
   ```
3. Make sure that `admin` UI is enabled, the configuration lives in */etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf* file

   [image: InfluxDB Enable Admin UI]
4. Start influxdb

   ```
   service influxdb start
   ```
5. Enjoy
6. Follow [How to Use Grafana to Monitor JMeter Non-GUI Results](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results) in order to connect JMeter to the InfluxDB

Comment: Now when we try to download influxdb version 1.2.0,the request is sent but in response we get 404 Not Found error, anyway to avoid it??

Comment: While running the install command getting this error: /usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: unable to read influxdb.service
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `influxdb' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `influxdb' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
Errors were encountered while processing:
 influxdb_1.2.0_amd64.deb

Comment: Most probably you have other version of InfluxDB running, you need to stop and uninstall previous one prior to executing `dpkg -i ...` command. If you cannot stop anything running try `systemctl unmask influxdb.service` command first

Comment: Another instance of influxDB was running and after killing it and running the **influxdb -config "location of config file"** command helped me to launch the influxb console on Ubuntu.